# Titanium android horizontal scrollable tableview

Tags: android, uitableview, scroll, titanium-mobile, horizontal-scrolling

Can we make a titanium android tableview scroll horizontally.
I tried this

```
var scrollAlbums = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
bottom : 10,
backgroundColor:'green',
contentHeight : Ti.UI.SIZE, // add this
contentWidth : Ti.UI.SIZE, // change this
height : 95,
layout : 'horizontal',
showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
showVerticalScrollIndicator : true, // should be a visual indication if can scroll
scrollType : 'horizontal',
horizontalWrap : false,
width : Ti.UI.FILL // assuming you need it full width - if not specify a width
});

// Create a TableView.
var aTableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({width:1000,backgroundColor:'red',height:200});
```

Please suggest me what should be the possible solution for that.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Titanium ScrollableView. That one will scroll horizontally.

Comment: Thanks Anand. Yes, I tried that but what I actually want is view should be only one like I make a tableview and define its large width and add in some horizontal scroller.Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot make a `tableview` scroll horizontally. But you can use a `scrollView` as `tableView`.

According to the documentation:

> Views added to the scroll view will be scrolled based on the size of
>   the scrollable region of content. If a scrollable region fits within the size of its scroll view, the view will not scroll.

On Android, you can scroll a scroll view only in one direction, either vertical or horizontal, and not both at the same time. You can use the **scrollType property to set the scroll direction** explicitly.

From Documentation:

> If the scrollType property is not defined, the scroll view attempts to
>   deduce the scroll direction based on some of the other properties that
>   have been set. Specifically, if contentWidth and width are both set
>   and are equal to each other, or if they are both set and
>   showVerticalScrollIndicator is set to true, then the scroll direction
>   is set to "vertical". If contentHeight and height are both set and are
>   equal, or if they are both set and showHorizontalScrollIndicator is
>   set to true, then the scroll direction is set to "horizontal". If
>   scrollType is set, it overrides the deduced setting.

Please have a look at the following example

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  exitOnClose: true,
  fullscreen: false,
  title: 'Horizontal ScrollView Demo'
});

var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  contentWidth  : 'auto',
  contentHeight : 'auto',
  scrollType    : 'horizontal',
  showHorizontalScrollIndicator: true
});

var containerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width       : 2000,
    layout      : 'horizontal',
    height      : 300,
    backgroundColor : '#000'
});

var columns = [];
for(var index=0;index<15;index++){
    columns[index] = Ti.UI.createView({
        width   : 200,
        height  : 200,
        backgroundColor : '#123456',
        left    : 20 
    });
    containerView.add(columns[index]);
}
scrollView.add(containerView);
win.add(scrollView);
win.open();
```

I have tried this and it's working. Hope it helped you.